# UIViewPropertyAnimator finish corresponding API

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit, uiviewpropertyanimator

Using the UIViewPropertyAnimator I can simply stop it and call finishAnimation(at: .end) to earlier finish ongoing animation. What API on iOS 9 would I have to use in order to achieve same behaviour using the traditional UIView block-based animations?